# How to wait for the end of the function

Tags: javascript, node.js, nodes

I have some task.
I'm creating my library which has a connection function written in it (several processes are included) and a creation function.
Need to clarify. The library doesn't deal with any http/https requests. Everything happens locally and without server requests.

Code from the testing side of the library

```js
module.exports = async function connect(argument) {
    const { save, models } = argument;

    var prom = new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        setTimeout(() => {
            checkDir(models);

            // check models
            checkBaseModels(models);
            checkModels(models);

            resolve();
        });
    });

    prom.then(() => {
        return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
            setTimeout(() => {
                loadModels();

                resolve();
            }, 2000);
        });
    }).then(() => {
        setTimeout(() => {
            saveModels(save);
            models_list();
        });
    });
};
```

```js
const cloud = require('cloud');

const cloud = cloud.connect({ save: 1000 });

const create = cloud.create({
    name: "Test",
    description: "Abc"
});
```

What can be used to make other processes stop while the connection in my library is running.

I need to somehow fix this problem without using setTimeout and so on in the test. It is desirable to leave this code as it is.

I need to connect first, and then create.
The code on the test side, if possible, should preferably not be edited.

Comment: `async` and `await` are your friends. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/async_function

Comment: what do you mean by *make other processes stop while the connection in my library is running*?

Comment: Not sure why you say "*The library doesn't deal with any http/https requests*". Would you know how to solve the problem if it did?

Comment: Do you have any could connect event

Comment: I have a creation process that happens faster than connect. It should be the other way around.
How can I fix this in the library code, not in the test?

Comment: If you change your code you'll invariably have to change the test too.

Comment: We need more context about `cloud.connect`, How it is working.

Comment: @ФОЗАН Please post the library code of the those two methods

Comment: @ФОЗАН Why all the `setTimeout`s in `connect`?  What are all these functions doing? Do you actually need this to be asynchronous at all?

Comment: @bergi, Yes. That's the way to do it.

Comment: @ФОЗАН No, it's not the way to do it. If there's no actual reason to make them asynchronous, don't make the artificially asynchronous! Keep them simple and synchronous, and your test code would simply work.

Answer (score 0):

`connect` function is not returning the promise

```
module.exports.connect = async function connect(argument) {
  //  ...
  return prom;
}
```

Connection file

```
(async () => {
  const cloud = await cloud.connect({ save: 1000 });
  const create = cloud.create({
    name: "Test",
    description: "Abc",
  });
})();
```

Comment: No. It's still faster to "create" than to "connect".